# jQuery UI: toggle with slide - lower divs move with the div above

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a few divs which have a headbar-div and a content-div. When I click on my toggle-symbol the content-div toggles out (= disappears) with the slide effect and only the headbar-div is still there.
This works very well, but there are a lot more divs under this one and when I minimize a div above, the div below is fixed in his old position until the slide-effect has finished. When the slide-effect has finished the div below will teleport himself directly under the recently minimized headbar.

How can I get it done, that the lower divs slide with the minimizing div?
I dont know whether it's important but all these divs are sortable (with jQuery UI).

However when I resize (with jQuery UI) the height of the divs, the lower divs move instantly.

**My Code**

```
$( ".togglepanelcontent" ).click(function() {
    var icon = $( this );
    icon.closest( ".panelgroup" ).find( ".panelcontent" ).toggle("slide", {direction: "up", duration: "slow", easing: "easeOutQuart"});
});
```

**how the divs behaive**

[image]

**how the divs should behaive**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried disabling the sortable plugin? Does that fix your problem?

Comment: By my reckoning your jQuery works. I put this fiddle together... making my best guess regarding your HTML layout... and it works as you want. https://jsfiddle.net/sc8fsvtd/1/ ... perhaps you've got something else in your CSS that is causing the problem?

Comment: Thank you Doug! It was `.slideToggle()`. With this code it works as I wanted :)